# setViewControllers of UINavigationController crash app when use with animation:NO

Tags: iphone

this is working very fine:

```
[(UINavigationController*)viewController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:cvc] animated:YES];
```

But This cause my application to crash:

```
[(UINavigationController*)viewController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:cvc] animated:NO];
```

the same line I have used in else part with different viewController with animation:NO and it is working fine. Am I missing something or it is a bug?

Comment: are you allocating memory to cvc with autorelease?

Comment: just check your cvc data before passing to navigation controller

Comment: not autorelease. but yes my project is ARC enable. This is line of code for cvc. CouponDetailViewController *cvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CouponView"];

Comment: cvc data is fine because if it was problem with cvc it should not work with animation:yes also.

Comment: and how many view controllers in cvc

Comment: cvc is a single viewController.

Comment: If you are setting your view controller as rootViewController then do this

    yourNavigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:cvc];

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting your view controller as rootViewController then do this

```
yourNavigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:cvc];
```

and then when you want to go to newViewController then use `pushViewController`

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewObject animated:YES];
```

Comment: my code is working fine every where else. I have used it in TabBarViewController. only at one place it is giving error and that also only when I use it with animation NO. it is working fine with animation YES.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has given the documentation of this function only with animation set to YES.

`- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_3_0);` 
// If animated is YES, then simulate a push or pop depending on whether the new top view controller was previously in the stack.

**I think when you set the animation to 'No' the new top-level NavigationController has not been initialized and loaded properly until the animation is done.**